# React native version mismatch after upgrading to 0.61.1 in brand new project

Tags: react-native

I am upgrading my React Native app from 0.59 to 0,61. What I did was to generate a brand new project from ground up with `react-native init emps_fe6` and `yarn add` each module in `package.json`. Also copy the components and `App.js` over to the new project. Here is my new `package.json` file:

```
{
  "name": "emps_fe6",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "test": "jest",
    "lint": "eslint ."
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-community/async-storage": "^1.6.2",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "react": "16.9.0",
    "react-native": "0.61.1",
    "react-native-cli": "^2.0.1",
    "react-native-confirmation-code-field": "^3.9.0",
    "react-native-device-info": "^3.1.4",
    "react-native-elements": "^1.2.3",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.4.1",
    "react-native-gifted-chat": "^0.10.1",
    "react-native-keychain": "^4.0.1",
    "react-native-linear-gradient": "^2.5.6",
    "react-native-modal": "^11.4.0",
    "react-native-modal-datetime-picker": "^7.6.0",
    "react-native-segmented-control-tab": "^3.4.1",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^6.6.0",
    "react-navigation": "^4.0.10",
    "socket.io-client": "2.1.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.6.2",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.6.2",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^0.0.5",
    "babel-jest": "^24.9.0",
    "eslint": "^6.5.1",
    "jest": "^24.9.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.56.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.9.0"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

Then start on Android emulator with `react-native run-android`. It throws out the error of version mismatch:

[image]

I don't quite understand what causes the error, as there is no reference to version `0.59.9` in components and `App.js` copied. The project is started from brand new and each module is `yarn add` individually. Only thing from previous version is the components and `App.js`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you had metro bundler running with a previous version of React Native which caused this issue. So, what I typically do when I face this problem is to start the bundler like `npm start --reset-cache`. Make sure to stop any metro bundler running.

If problem persist try restarting your machine.

Comment: In my case, this is working only once (and when version mismatch error is gone I get this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58659906/turbomoduleregistry-getenforcing-networking-could-not-be-found-verify-that-a). Once I say react-native run-ios again, the error will come up once more..