# TurboModuleRegistry.getEnforcing 'Networking' could not be found. Verify that a module by this name is registered in the native binary

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

After solving lots and lots of build problems my app finally builds successfully. But now I am fighting this problem. I see this after the app builds successfully and starts launching on the iOS simulator.

**My podfile**:

```
platform :ios, '9.0'
use_frameworks!

target 'myProject' do

pod 'FBReactNativeSpec', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/FBReactNativeSpec"
pod 'RCTRequired', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/RCTRequired"
pod 'RCTTypeSafety', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/TypeSafety"
pod 'FBLazyVector', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/FBLazyVector"
  pod 'React', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/'
  pod 'React-Core', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/'
pod 'React-CoreModules', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/React/CoreModules'
  pod 'React-Core/DevSupport', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/'
  pod 'React-RCTActionSheet', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/ActionSheetIOS'
  pod 'React-RCTAnimation', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/NativeAnimation'
  pod 'React-RCTBlob', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Blob'
  pod 'React-RCTImage', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Image'
  pod 'React-RCTLinking', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/LinkingIOS'
  pod 'React-RCTNetwork', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Network'
  pod 'React-RCTSettings', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Settings'
  pod 'React-RCTText', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Text'
  pod 'React-RCTVibration', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Vibration'
  pod 'React-Core/RCTWebSocket', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/'


  pod 'React-cxxreact', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/cxxreact'
  pod 'React-jsi', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/jsi'
  pod 'React-jsiexecutor', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/jsiexecutor'
  pod 'React-jsinspector', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/jsinspector'
pod 'ReactCommon/turbomodule/core', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon"
  pod 'Yoga', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/yoga'

  pod 'DoubleConversion', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/DoubleConversion.podspec'
  pod 'glog', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/glog.podspec'
  pod 'Folly', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/Folly.podspec'

  pod 'RNCharts', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-charts-wrapper'

  pod 'QBImagePickerController', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-image-crop-picker/ios/QBImagePicker/QBImagePickerController.podspec'

  pod 'RNImageCropPicker', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-image-crop-picker'


   pod 'Firebase/Core', '~> 6.3.0'

    pre_install do |installer|
        installer.analysis_result.specifications.each do |s|
            s.swift_version = '5.0' unless s.swift_version
        end
    end

end
```

[image]

**react-native-cli**: 2.0.1
**react-native**: 0.61.1
**cocoapods**: 1.8.4

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: Did you solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I also go the same error but it was my fault. I used **"="** while using the **Platform API** instead of **"==="**. This polluted the global environment. I would suggest you to recheck your code for resolving this error.